# Клавиатурный тренажер на C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Метод SelectionColor не работает, уже везде посмотрел, но не получилось решить.

```
public FormGame()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UpdateTargetText();
}

private void FormGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    targetText = targetTextBox.Text;
    inputTextBox.Focus();
}

private void UpdateTargetText()
{
    targetTextBox.Text = targetText;
    targetTextBox.SelectAll();
    //targetTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(inputTextBox.Text.Length, targetText.Length); i++)
    {
        if (inputTextBox.Text[i] != targetText[i])              
        {
            targetTextBox.SelectionStart = i;                               
            targetTextBox.SelectionLength = 1;
            //targetTextBox.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            mistakesCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: TextBox не содержит определения SelectionColor, и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения SelectionColor

Comment: вопрос решен.
необходимо было поставить richTextBox вместо обычного textBox)

Comment: в таком случае вы можете его удалить или написать подробный ответ